# Coupling Amazon EC2, Amazon S3 and Android app for photo sharing

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I decided to go with Amazon AWS for my Android cloud app, which is a photo sharing app. I set up an instance on EC2 with PHP and MySql, for handling simple requests and storing basic user information. I also set up a S3 service to store all the photos.

But now I'd like some advice. I'm not sure how to handle the three together. Should the EC2 server always be used as a mediator between the end-user using the app and the S3 service? Or should the end-user on Android communicate directly with S3 when it can?

Say for example the user registers on my app and decides to upload a picture. Should I send the JPEG to my EC2 server, and then let the server send the pic to S3? Or should the I send it directly to S3, get the URL back on the device and then send it to my EC2 server? Either way, I need to store the S3 url addresses in my MySQL database as to send them to the other users, so they can access the newly public images.

Any idea on how I should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really have a choice. You're going to have to go through EC2 for security's sake. If the phone app uploads directly to S3 it means that the S3 bucket is either publicly writable or the access credentials are stored on the user's phone, both of which are dangerous. That means you'll need to upload through EC2 or at least have EC2 issue time limited credentials to S3 (not sure if the latter is possible or a good idea).

If you're willing to allow anyone to view any picture, then you can have the S3 instance publicly readable and the phone app can just get the url from the EC2 instance and then download the picture directly from S3. That would alleviate some of the EC2 load.

Another way to alleviate EC2 load is to have a dedicated EC2 instance just for handling uploads separate from the instance running your database. That way if your upload server is getting hammered, your app can still hit the database, retrieve S3 urls, and download pics.

You'll need to think about scalability of your app and up time also. Amazon doesn't have any up time guarantee for a single EC2 instance or even a single availability zone so if you want your servers to be there reliably you'll want to scale at least across two availability zones. (Two regions isn't a bad idea either, but is overkill for most applications.)